# Length function for generic lists

Tags: list, function, generics, z3, axiom

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473042/list-concat-in-z3) shows how to axiomatise a length function for Z3's built-in lists. However, the function is sort-specific (here Int) and not applicable to lists of bools or custom sorts.

```
; declare len as an uninterpreted function
(declare-fun len ((List Int)) Int)

; assert defining equations for len as an axiom
(assert (forall ((xs (List Int)))
  (ite (= nil xs)
    (= 0 (len xs))
    (= (+ 1 (len (tail xs))) (len xs)))))
```

What would be the smartest way of encoding sort-generic list functions? (If I remember correctly, functions cannot be generic per se).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMT 2.0 format or Z3 do *not* support parametric axioms in SMT 2.0 scripts. One alternative is to use the programmatic APIs. You can create functions that create the `len` axiom for a given sort. Here is an example on how to do it using the Python API.

http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/vNa

```
from z3 import *
def MkList(sort):
    List = Datatype('List')
    List.declare('insert', ('head', sort), ('tail', List))
    List.declare('nil')
    return List.create()


def MkLen(sort):
    List = MkList(sort)
    Len  = Function('len', List, IntSort())
    x    = Const('x', List)
    Ax   = ForAll(x, If(x == List.nil, Len(x) == 0, Len(x) == 1 + Len(List.tail(x))))
    return (Len, [Ax])

IntList = MkList(IntSort())
IntLen,  IntLenAxioms = MkLen(IntSort())
print IntLenAxioms
s = Solver()
l1 = Const('l1', IntList)
s.add(IntLenAxioms)
s.add(IntLen(l1) == 0)
s.add(l1 == IntList.insert(10, IntList.nil))
print s.check()
```

Comment: Looks as if I have to switch from stdio to a programmatic API sooner than I thought ... thanks!

Comment: Something else: is it necessary to guard such defining equations with patterns? As I would usually do with quantified axioms.

Also, the guide says that quantifiers defining pseudo-macros are automatically detected by the Model Finder. I assume that this requires :mbqi to be true (which it isn't in my case). Could you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: If we do not provide patterns, Z3 will compute them for us. The `Len` axiom is not a pseudo-macro because it is a "recursive" definition. The option :mbqi is true by default.

Comment: Does this in reverse mean that all non-recursive definitions are pseudo-macros? Also, what impact do pseudo-macros have on the behaviour of Z3? If I deactivate :mbqi, are pseudo-macros still treated specially?

Comment: Yes, all non-recursive definitions are treated as macros by the `:mbqi` engine. One problem is that `:mbqi` may not have a chance to run. Z3 only executes this engine when it builds a "candidate interpretation" that satisfies all quantifier-free constraints. If you want to make sure that all definitions are expanded before the search starts, you can add the option `(set-option :macro-finder true)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sort for that. The `len` function is defined over a generic List of a user-defined sort `T`. Only the first `define-sort` links `T` to an `Int` type.

```
(define-sort T () Int)
(define-sort MyList() (List T))

(declare-const listlen Int)
(declare-const a MyList)
(declare-const b MyList)
(declare-const c MyList)
(declare-const d MyList)
(declare-const e MyList)

(define-fun-rec len((l MyList)) Int
    (ite
        (= l nil)
        0
        (+ (len (tail l)) 1)
    )
)
(assert (= a nil))
(assert (= b (insert 2 a)))
(assert (= c (insert 8 b)))
(assert (= d (insert 6 c)))
(assert (= e (insert 10 d)))

(assert (= listlen (len e)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```